# Exception Processing Mirror-Quickstart

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, google-mirror-api, google-glass

I ran the mvn war:war in the command prompt, I then went to upload to appengine using appcfg update and I got this error. The app works on localhost. Aside from the path simply being wrong, there is no appengine-web.xml. Any help would be appreciated thankyou.

```
C:\appengine-java-sdk\bin>appcfg update C:\mirror-quickstart-java-master
Reading application configuration data...
Aug 31, 2013 7:10:33 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
SEVERE: Received exception processing C:/mirror-quickstart-java-master\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Could not locate C:\mirror-quickstart-java-master\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.getInputStream(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:140)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.readAppEngineWebXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:75)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.<init>(Application.java:182)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.readApplication(Application.java:319)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.readWar(AppCfg.java:279)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.readApplication(AppCfg.java:270)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:208)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:121)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:117)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\mirror-quickstart-java-master\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.getInputStream(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:137)
        ... 8 more

Bad configuration: Could not locate C:\mirror-quickstart-java-master\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml
  Caused by: C:\mirror-quickstart-java-master\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
Please see the logs [C:\Users\Hasan\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg4724142030047376778.log] for further information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of the mirror-quickstart-java that supports Google App Engine has been tagged with [`app-engine`](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-java/tree/app-engine); you should use this specific release.

Comment: When I run the mvn war:war I get errors saying that this is malformed project and when I go to upload to app engine it says that it is missing files.